# How to achieve that placeholder text disappears character by character in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, placeholder

Can you please help me.

In `UITextField` when we provide a placeholder text its placeholder string will be gone when we enter any character. How can I achieve that only entered character will be gone not a full string? Meaning that if I type in 3 characters, only the first 3 characters of placeholder will be gone.

[image]

**#EDIT 1**

Also, newly entered character text color will change and other remaining character text color remains same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no need of placeholder, create the overlay and set the same bounds of your textfiled, based on textfield char it automatically hides

Comment: Ya ... That's a trick but I want to achieve using code by overriding default placeholder property. Thanks.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Actually your solution doesn't work When I want to replace '_' underscore with specific char like 'A' or '10' then there is a mismatch in the string.

Comment: I guess you have to do this with overlay. @Anbu.Karthik is true.

Comment: _ (underscore) you need to calculate based on input string user given the input

Comment: Ok, I will do but there are no other workarounds to use this using default placeholder property?

Comment: ur placeholder text length is 8 , but user input is 4 so you need to calculate every text < 7 chars

Comment: by default default placeholder property not available related to ur concept,

Comment: but your question is good, i will add my answer, for e.g add contact number (xxx) - xxxx

Comment: Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Actually, I have already implemented it. Setting text shown in the image and replacing individual character input entered by the user with the underscore.

Comment: underscore we need to append for every char input, is this possible to attch your project , it is easy to resolve

Comment: Ya I have already done it using textfield text property but my question is for placeholder text.

Comment: simple bro, can you attach your project what you have done

Comment: Okay, I will put my own Answer for this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153857/discussion-between-vishal16-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the default behavior of the placeholder is editable, but what you are trying to accomplish can be done using `NSAttributedString` to simulate the placeholder value.

I'm sure this can be optimized, but here I have created a handler class that acts as the delegate for a given `UITextField`, manipulating the string the user inputs to achieve the desired effect. You init the handler with your desired placeholder string, so you can make any text field work this way.

[image: Custom Placeholder Text Field]

```
import UIKit

class CustomPlaceholderTextFieldHandler: NSObject {
    let placeholderText: String
    let placeholderAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.lightGray]
    let inputAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 153/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)]
    var input = ""

    init(placeholder: String) {
        self.placeholderText = placeholder
        super.init()
    }

    func resetPlaceholder(for textField: UITextField) {
        input = ""
        setCombinedText(for: textField)
    }

    fileprivate func setCursorPosition(for textField: UITextField) {
        guard let cursorPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: input.characters.count)
            else { return }

        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: cursorPosition, to: cursorPosition)
    }

    fileprivate func setCombinedText(for textField: UITextField) {
        let placeholderSubstring = placeholderText.substring(from: input.endIndex)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: input + placeholderSubstring, attributes: placeholderAttributes)
        attributedString.addAttributes(inputAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count))
        textField.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}

extension CustomPlaceholderTextFieldHandler: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if string == "" {
            if input.characters.count > 0 {
                input = input.substring(to: input.index(before: input.endIndex))
            }
        } else {
            input += string
        }

        if input.characters.count <= placeholderText.characters.count {
            setCombinedText(for: textField)
            setCursorPosition(for: textField)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        setCursorPosition(for: textField)
    }
}
```

Here's a the way I initialized the gif above:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    let placeholderHandler = CustomPlaceholderTextFieldHandler(placeholder: "_2_-__-__A")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = placeholderHandler
        placeholderHandler.resetPlaceholder(for: textField)
    }
}
```

This could be expanded to take color parameters, fonts, etc. at initialization, or you may find it cleaner to subclass `UITextField` and make it its own delegate. I also haven't really tested this for selecting/deleting/replacing multiple characters.

The `input` variable will return the text the user has input at any given point. Also, using a fixed-width font would remove the jitteriness as the user types and replaces the placeholder text.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using placeholder text, use a UILabel below your textfield and give the same font style to both. the label text should be 
like "- - - - -"

And when user starts typing on textfield give a space after each character press.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField.text?.characters.count == 0 && string.characters.count != 0 {
        textField.text = textField.text! + " "
    }
     else {
        return false
    }

    if textField.text?.characters.count == 1 && string.characters.count != 0 {
        textField.text = textField.text! + " "
    }
    else {
        return false
    }

    if textField.text?.characters.count == 2 && string.characters.count != 0 {
        textField.text = textField.text! + " "
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
    if textField.text?.characters.count == 3 && string.characters.count != 0 {
        textField.text = textField.text! + " "
    }
    else {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Okay. Nice solution but I am waiting for some more responses but If there is no other way to do this thing. I will accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

There is my solution using UITextField text property

```
+(BOOL)shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
                   replacementString:(NSString *)string
                           textField:(UITextField *)textField
                                mask:(NSString *)mask withMaskTemplate:(NSString *)maskTemplate{

    NSString * alreadyExistString = @"";
    if (string.length == 0) {
        alreadyExistString = textField.text;
        for (int i = range.location; i >= 0; i--) {
            unichar  currentCharMask = [maskTemplate characterAtIndex:i];
            unichar  currentChar = [alreadyExistString characterAtIndex:i];
            if (currentCharMask == currentChar) {// fixed value and _
                continue;
            }else{
                alreadyExistString = [alreadyExistString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) withString:@"_"];
                break;
            }
        }
        textField.text = alreadyExistString;
        return NO;
    }else{
        alreadyExistString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(range.location, 1) withString:string];
    }

    NSMutableString * validText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    int last = 0;
    BOOL append = NO;
    for (int i = 0; i < alreadyExistString.length; i++) {
        unichar  currentCharMask = [mask characterAtIndex:i];
        unichar  currentChar = [alreadyExistString characterAtIndex:i];
        BOOL isLetter = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] characterIsMember: currentChar];
        BOOL isDigit  = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember: currentChar];
        if ((isLetter && currentCharMask == '#') || (isDigit && currentCharMask == '9')) {
            [validText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",currentChar]];
        }else{
            if (currentCharMask == '#' || currentCharMask == '9') {
                break;
            }
            if ((isLetter && currentCharMask!= currentChar)|| (isDigit && currentCharMask!= currentChar)) {
                append = YES;
            }
            [validText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",currentCharMask]];
        }
        last = i;
    }

    for (int i = last+1; i < mask.length; i++) {
        unichar currentCharMask = [mask characterAtIndex:i];
        if (currentCharMask != '#' && currentCharMask != '9') {
            [validText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",currentCharMask]];
        }
        if (currentCharMask == '#' || currentCharMask == '9') {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (append) {
        [validText appendString:string];
    }

    NSString *placeHolderMask = textField.text;
    NSString *sub = [validText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location, 1)];
    placeHolderMask = [placeHolderMask stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(range.location, 1) withString:sub];
    textField.text = placeHolderMask;
    return NO;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * maskTemplate;// like: _2_-__-__A
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * mask;// like: #2#-99-##A
```

- Initially set text field text to mask template
- Then when user enters input shouldChangeCharactersInRange invoked and it does a great job

**#Edit 1**
There is also some more code I have implemented which move the cursor to the underscore location. If someone need help. Please comment I will help you.

**#Edit 2**

Problems I have facing using this approached

- Not able to change individual text color. The color will be same for both the string like @"_" underscore and input characters has the same color.
- If user not providing any input then I have to provide a check to send blank as a string.
- Tracking for individual inputs.

Thanks,
Still waiting for if there is any other workaround using Placeholder String.

Comment: Please add complete procedure. (Create a class with name and implement it in the code).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is just what you are looking for. Create your `UITextField` object with the text `_2_-__-__A` (not placeholder text). Then, use its view controller as delegate, and add that to the view controller:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string{
    if (range.length>1) return NO; // Avoids removing multiple characters at once
    if (range.location==1) range.location++;  // '2' index
    if (range.location==3) range.location++;  // '-' index
    if (range.location==6) range.location++;  // '-' index
    if (range.location==9)  return NO; // 'A' index
    if (range.location==10) return NO; // String end
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) return NO; //Avoids removing characters

    if (range.length==0) {
        range.length++;
        UITextPosition *beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument;
        UITextPosition *start = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
        UITextPosition *end = [textField positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
        UITextRange *textRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
        [textField setSelectedTextRange:textRange];
    }

    return YES;
}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField{
    UITextPosition *beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:0];
    UITextPosition *end = [textField positionFromPosition:start offset:0];
    UITextRange *textRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:textRange];
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField{
    [passwordInput resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

It should work as intended.

Answer (score -1):

For that situation use attributed string in swift like bellow,

```
let attributeFontSaySomething : [String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)]
let attributeColorSaySomething : [String : Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue]

var attributes = attributeFontSaySomething
for (key, value) in attributeColorSaySomething {
    attributes(value, forKey: key)
}

let attStringSaySomething = NSAttributedString(string: "Say something", attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: Not a solution attributedPlacholderString will gone when we enter any input.

Answer (score -3):

No You can not do this without make a custom layer on UITextfield after making it you need to check char entered does matched in placehoder string ,then only that charecter ll be replaced.
see also [Replacing character after each type in UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502130/replacing-character-after-each-type-in-uitextfield)

Comment: Okay. I will try but I want to replace placeholder individual text. You can see when we enter any input character full placeholder string was gone. I want to override its default behavior.

Comment: okay i am tring to make a demo pls wait,i revert u if can make it.